# AWS Device Farm with hybrid apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework

I am trying to use aws solution to testing my app .. my question is i've to type test scripts on my code in order to implement test sceneries or aws handle this ?? and which test configure type i must choose

1. Appium java Junit
2. Appium testNG
3. Calabash
4. ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS has some built in tests for iOS and Android. In the case of Android we can use fuzz tests which randomly swipes and clicks on the screen or we can use the Built-in tests which does a depth first search of the views and clicks around.

For iOS we just has the fuzz tests. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-built-in-tests.html

If we want to write out own tests then we must ask ourself who is writing the tests.  If we want a behavioral driven framework where you write plain English then we should choose Calabash. If we would like to programatically find elements and click items  we should use appium or one of the native test frameworks (XCUITests or instrumentation)

There are some sample tests and apps here to get started.

https://github.com/aws-samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Device+farm&type=&language=

Hth

James